# my proxy server doesn't work as expected

Tags: java, sockets, socket.io

I developed  a simple, multi-threaded proxy server. Note that this program  is a proxy for one specific server. Here is my code :

```
    public class Proxy {

    int remotePort;
    InetAddress remoteHost;

    public Proxy(InetAddress remoteHost, int remotePort) {
        this.remotePort = remotePort;
        this.remoteHost = remoteHost;
    }

    public void go() {
        ExecutorService pool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        try (ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(2015);) {
            System.out.println("Proxy is running....!");
            while (true) {
                Socket socketClient = server.accept();
                System.out.println("client connected...!");
                Socket socketServer = new Socket(remoteHost, remotePort);
                System.out.println("connection established with the server...!");
                Worker p1 = new Worker(socketClient, socketServer);
                Worker p2 = new Worker(socketServer, socketClient);
                pool.execute(p1);
                pool.execute(p2);

            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

    }

    class Worker implements Runnable {

        Socket from, to;

        public Worker(Socket from, Socket to) {
            this.from = from;
            this.to = to;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            try (BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(from.getInputStream());
                    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(to.getOutputStream());) {
                while (true) {
                    int octet = bis.read();
                    if (octet == -1) {
                        break;
                    }
                    bos.write(octet);

                }
                bos.flush();
                from.close();
                to.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }

        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InetAddress adr = null;
        try {
            adr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        new Proxy(adr, 2020).go();
    }

}
```

I would like to test this proxy server with a client and a server. the client sends an array of integers to find the maximum. the server of his turn, returns the maximum of a received array. 
the problem is the following: the proxy server is not playing its role. the array is not sent to the server and the client  not received the maximum value of its array.
The code of my Server is as follow:

```
    public class ServerTCPMax {

    static void display(int[] tab) {
        for (int u : tab) {
            System.out.print(u + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();

    }

    static int searchMax(int[] t) {
        int max = t[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < t.length; i++) {
            if (t[i] > max) {
                max = t[i];
            }
        }
        return max;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(2020);
            System.out.println("server is running .......!  ");
            while (true) {
                try (Socket sclient = server.accept()) {
                    System.out.println("Proxy connected...!");
                    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(sclient.getInputStream());
                    int[] tab = (int[]) ois.readObject();
                    display(tab);
                    int max = searchMax(tab);
                    try (DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(sclient.getOutputStream())) {
                        dos.writeInt(max);
                        dos.flush();

                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

The following code represents my client:

```
 public class ClientTCPMax {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] A = {3, -7, 9, 22, 0, 7, 11, 2};
        try {
            try (Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 2015)) {
                System.out.println("connection established with the Proxy ...!");
                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                oos.writeObject(A);
                oos.flush();
                DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                int max = dis.readInt();
                System.out.println(" the max is : " + max);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```